# I want to copy a date time value from n excel cell to another without converting

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, excel-formula, datetime-format

[Excel Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qjv4a.png)

This is how my table looks. I am writing  a formula in my last cell (**Column K**) which is a SQL query based on values from Columns A through J.

The highlighted portion in the below image is how my formula looks at the moment

[Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9uJF.png)

The problem is that the DATETIME I have in Columns C & D gets converted to decimals once i place them in the formula like can be seen in the third image.
I want them to reflect as-is (ie yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:ss).

[DATETIME as Decimal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40ELw.png)

Comment: What format are your column C and D?

Comment: @Zac - They are Custom (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:ss) formats